# how to Write query with subquery using where not in clause in laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

i want to write a query with sub-query in laravel 5.2 using where not in clause and below i have wrote the SQL query for what i needed.can some one help me to write this query in laravel 5.2 model class

```
SELECT
SYSTEM."in_ccws_state"."state_id",
SYSTEM."in_ccws_state"."state"
FROM
SYSTEM."in_ccws_state"
WHERE
SYSTEM."in_ccws_state"."state_id" NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT 

SYSTEM."in_ccws_enable_state"."state_id"
FROM SYSTEM."in_ccws_enable_state"
)
```

i have tried to write it in below method

```
 $data = DB::table('in_ccws_state')->whereNotIn('state_id', function($q){
            $q->select('state_id')->from('in_ccws_enable_state');
        })->pluck('in_ccws_state.state', 'in_ccws_state.state_id');
 return $data;
```

as i need to load the data to the dropdown i have used the "pluck()" instead of "get()"

Comment: Use `DB::select` for core query

Comment: i have edited my question with the tried code. but its not working error displaying as method select not found in class

Comment: Try this  `\DB::` instead of `DB::`